# Escape special characters in text field of pdf form

Tags: hyperref

I am using `hyperref` to render a form. I would like to initially fill the text fields with some dynamic content. Therefore, I have to escape special characters in the content. I managed to discover how I can escape `&`, `%`, `$`, `#`, `_`, and `^` by trial and error but how can I escape `\`, `{`, `}`, and `~`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\TextField[value={&\%$\#_^}]{}

% \TextField[value={\{}~}]{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the `~`, `\TextField[value={\~{}}]{}` seems to work, as well as `\textasciitilde`. The [Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf), p.10, recommends to use `\textbackslash`, `\textbraceleft`, `\{` and `\}` for the other symbols you are looking for, but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using the macro `\pdfstringdef`.
[image: Output of example code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

\TextField[value={&\%$\#_^}]{}
\pdfstringdef{\foo}{\textbackslash\{\}\~{}}
\TextField[value={\foo}]{}

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```